# Turtlebot gazebo simulator available in groovy?

Tags: ros, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the [turtlebot wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot) for groovy, it says that turtlebot_simulator is coming soon.

However, I see the following Ubuntu 12.04 package available: ros-groovy-turtlebot-simulator

Has anyone gotten turtlebot working in groovy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55697/turtlebot-gazebo-simulator-available-in-groovy?/) by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See also [this related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/52995/state-of-turtlebot-simulation-using-gazebo-in-fuerte-and-groovy/).

Short summary: It is available as a package for groovy but it does not work.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0